# Converting a .bat executable to Mac

Tags: macos, conversion, automator

I need some help converting a .bat executable file that I run on our PC at my job so that it works on a mac. Before we upload tar files to our website we run this script which to the best of my knowledge simply unlocks all of the permissions to the tar and all the images within.

If someone could help me in "translating" it to run on my Mac that would be awesome! I was hoping I could set up something in Automator

Here's the code

> del images5.tar
>
> move images4.tar images5.tar
>
> move images3.tar images4.tar
>
> move images2.tar images3.tar
>
> move images.tar images2.tar
>
> cd ..
>
> tar --mode=777 -rvf images.tar *.jpg
>
> tar --mode=777 -rvf images.tar p
>
> move images.tar ./tarpics

Comment: Have you simply tried running the existing file on a Mac by chance?  If it already works on a Unix/Linux computer because OS X is based on Unix it should work.  This isn't a Windows .bat file.

Comment: @Ramhound It is. There's no `del` or `move` on OS X. It's only `tar`, and that's available for Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
  DOS/Windows     Unix
  del             rm
  move            mv
  cd              cd
  tar             tar
```

But do check the man pages (or `tar --help`) for tar on both systems for `--mode` and `-r` options. Probably OK if both are GNU tar.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh 
rm images5.tar
mv images4.tar images5.tar
mv images3.tar images4.tar
mv images2.tar images3.tar
mv images.tar images2.tar
cd ..
tar --mode=777 -rvf images.tar *.jpg
tar --mode=777 -rvf images.tar p
mv images.tar ./tarpics
```

You probably want a shell script, as shell scripts are the UNIX equivalent for bat files.

Just do `nano whatever.sh` in terminal, copy this code in, press Control-X, and y to save it, run `chmod +x whatever.sh` to make it executable then do `./whatever.sh` to run it.

Comment: Don't forget the shebang.  To make a proper shell script, add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.